# Creating data in Prefuse

Tags: graph, population, prefuse

I am new to Prefuse. The demo examples are all loaded data from a file/database. Is there any way to create the data dynamically instead of loading from file. For example, I want to create a tree data structure and visualize this. Any simple working example would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 6):

I've just been attacking this problem.  Here's a tweaked version of `Example.java` which shows one way to make it happen.

Instead of loading data from `socialnet.xml`, I'm generating it programatically (based on `Aggregate.java` but without the aggregation stuff) and adding one field to each `Node` and each `Edge`.  The `Node` field is a simple boolean flag which controls the colour it's rendered; the `Edge` field is a label - but it's *not* being rendered yet.  I'm still working on that one! :-)

The question-specific code is in `makeGraph()`.  The basic approach is to create a `Table` (well, one each for nodes and edges), and add columns to those tables defining the shape of the data; then when you add your nodes and edges, you can add the corresponding data.  One gotcha is that for edges you *must* include columns for the edge's source/target nodes - see the `Graph` and `Table` documentation for more details.  There are other ways to do this (e.g. involving `Schema`) but I haven't sussed them out yet.

Hope this helps.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import prefuse.Constants;
import prefuse.Display;
import prefuse.Visualization;
import prefuse.action.ActionList;
import prefuse.action.RepaintAction;
import prefuse.action.assignment.ColorAction;
import prefuse.action.assignment.DataColorAction;
import prefuse.action.layout.graph.ForceDirectedLayout;
import prefuse.activity.Activity;
import prefuse.controls.DragControl;
import prefuse.controls.PanControl;
import prefuse.controls.ZoomControl;
import prefuse.data.Edge;
import prefuse.data.Graph;
import prefuse.data.Node;
import prefuse.data.Table;
import prefuse.render.DefaultRendererFactory;
import prefuse.render.EdgeRenderer;
import prefuse.render.Renderer;
import prefuse.render.ShapeRenderer;
import prefuse.util.ColorLib;
import prefuse.visual.VisualItem;

public class Example extends Display {

    private Graph makeGraph() {

        // Create tables for node and edge data, and configure their columns.
        Table nodeData = new Table();
        Table edgeData = new Table(0,1);
        nodeData.addColumn("flag", boolean.class);
        edgeData.addColumn(Graph.DEFAULT_SOURCE_KEY, int.class);
        edgeData.addColumn(Graph.DEFAULT_TARGET_KEY, int.class);
        edgeData.addColumn("label", String.class);
        // Need more data in your nodes or edges?  Just add more
        // columns.

        // Create Graph backed by those tables.  Note that I'm
        // creating a directed graph here also.
        Graph g = new Graph(nodeData, edgeData, true);

        // Create some nodes and edges, each carrying some data.
        // There are surely prettier ways to do this, but for the
        // example it gets the job done.
        for ( int i=0; i<3; ++i ) {
            Node n1 = g.addNode();
            Node n2 = g.addNode();
            Node n3 = g.addNode();
            n1.setBoolean("flag", false);
            n2.setBoolean("flag", true);
            n3.setBoolean("flag", true);
            Edge e1 = g.addEdge(n1, n2);
            Edge e2 = g.addEdge(n1, n3);
            Edge e3 = g.addEdge(n2, n3);
            e1.setString("label", "a");
            e2.setString("label", "a");
            e3.setString("label", "a");
        }
        Edge e4 = g.getEdge(g.addEdge(0, 3));
        Edge e5 = g.getEdge(g.addEdge(3, 6));
        Edge e6 = g.getEdge(g.addEdge(6, 0));
        e4.setString("label", "b");
        e5.setString("label", "b");
        e6.setString("label", "b");
        return g;
    }

    public Example() {

        super(new Visualization());

        Graph graph = makeGraph();

        m_vis.addGraph("graph", graph);
        m_vis.setInteractive("graph.edges", null, false);
        m_vis.setValue("graph.nodes", null, VisualItem.SHAPE,
                new Integer(Constants.SHAPE_ELLIPSE));

        Renderer nodeR = new ShapeRenderer(20);
        EdgeRenderer edgeR = new EdgeRenderer(prefuse.Constants.EDGE_TYPE_CURVE, prefuse.Constants.EDGE_ARROW_FORWARD);

        DefaultRendererFactory drf = new DefaultRendererFactory();
        drf.setDefaultRenderer(nodeR);
        drf.setDefaultEdgeRenderer(edgeR);
        m_vis.setRendererFactory(drf);

        int[] palette = new int[] {
            ColorLib.rgb(255,180,180), ColorLib.rgb(190,190,255)
        };
        ColorAction nStroke = new ColorAction("graph.nodes", VisualItem.STROKECOLOR);
        nStroke.setDefaultColor(ColorLib.gray(100));

        DataColorAction nFill = new DataColorAction("graph.nodes", "flag",
            Constants.NOMINAL, VisualItem.FILLCOLOR, palette);
        ColorAction edges = new ColorAction("graph.edges",
            VisualItem.STROKECOLOR, ColorLib.gray(200));
        ColorAction arrow = new ColorAction("graph.edges",
            VisualItem.FILLCOLOR, ColorLib.gray(200));
        ActionList color = new ActionList();
        color.add(nStroke);
        color.add(nFill);
        color.add(edges);
        color.add(arrow);

        ActionList layout = new ActionList(Activity.INFINITY);
        layout.add(new ForceDirectedLayout("graph"));
        layout.add(new RepaintAction());

        m_vis.putAction("color", color);
        m_vis.putAction("layout", layout);

        setSize(720, 500); // set display size
        pan(360, 250);
        setHighQuality(true);
        addControlListener(new DragControl());
        addControlListener(new PanControl());
        addControlListener(new ZoomControl());

        m_vis.run("color");
        m_vis.run("layout");

    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Example ex = new Example();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("prefuse example");
        frame.getContentPane().add(ex);
        frame.pack();           // layout components in window
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true); // show the window
    }

}
```